# How can I adjust the range of the value by which I calculate a correlation in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm working with data related to cryptocurrency market.

Tables:
`fact_marketPrices [date, currency, price]`
`dim_currencies[code, name]`
`dim_dateRange[date, year, month, etc.]`

relationships:
`dim_currencies[code] 1:n fact_marketPrices[currency`]
`dim_dateRange[date] 1:n fact_marketPrices[date]`

My goal is to calculate the correlation between price of Bitcoin and the second currency (selected from a slicer) over time.

I created a new table dim_BTC_Price storing the data where `fact_marketPrices[currency] = 'BTC'`.
Then I used a quick measure to calculate correlation between `dim_BTC_Price[price]` and `fact_marketPrices[date]` by `dim_dateRange[date]`.

I've got the following formula

```
c Selected to BTC = 
    VAR __CORRELATION_TABLE = VALUES('dim_dateRange'[date])
    VAR __COUNT =
        COUNTX(
            KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
            CALCULATE(SUM('dim_BTC_Price'[price]) * SUM('fact_marketPrices'[price]))
        )
    VAR __SUM_X =
        SUMX(
            KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
            CALCULATE(SUM('dim_BTC_Price'[price]))
        )
    VAR __SUM_Y =
        SUMX(
            KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
            CALCULATE(SUM('fact_marketPrices'[price]))
        )
    VAR __SUM_XY =
        SUMX(
            KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
            CALCULATE(SUM('dim_BTC_Price'[price]) * SUM('fact_marketPrices'[price]) * 1.)
        )
    VAR __SUM_X2 =
        SUMX(
            KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
            CALCULATE(SUM('dim_BTC_Price'[price]) ^ 2)
        )
    VAR __SUM_Y2 =
        SUMX(
            KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
            CALCULATE(SUM('fact_marketPrices'[price]) ^ 2)
        )
    RETURN
        DIVIDE(
            __COUNT * __SUM_XY - __SUM_X * __SUM_Y * 1.,
            SQRT(
                (__COUNT * __SUM_X2 - __SUM_X ^ 2)
                    * (__COUNT * __SUM_Y2 - __SUM_Y ^ 2)
            )
        )
```

In works for the cases where date range for both currencies is the same. When the second currency has shorter date range, the correlation exceeds the value o 1.

[Correct calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgB6D.png)

[Wrong calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drOh6.png)

I tried to modify the formula so it only takes into account the date range of the second currency, selected from a slicer.

```
3c Selected to BTC = 
VAR __SelectedCurrency = SELECTEDVALUE('dim_currencies'[name])

VAR __CORRELATION_TABLE =
    FILTER(
        VALUES('dim_dateRange'[date]),
        MIN(dim_currencies[name]) = __SelectedCurrency
    )

VAR __COUNT =
    COUNTX(
        __CORRELATION_TABLE,
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('dim_BTC_Price'[price]) * SUM('fact_marketPrices'[price]),
            __SelectedCurrency
        )
    )

VAR __SUM_X =
    SUMX(
        __CORRELATION_TABLE,
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('dim_BTC_Price'[price]),
            __SelectedCurrency
       )
    )

VAR __SUM_Y =
    SUMX(
        __CORRELATION_TABLE,
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('fact_marketPrices'[price]),
           __SelectedCurrency
        )
    )

VAR __SUM_XY =
    SUMX(
        __CORRELATION_TABLE,
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('dim_BTC_Price'[price]) * SUM('fact_marketPrices'[price]) * 1.,
            __SelectedCurrency
        )
    )

VAR __SUM_X2 =
    SUMX(
        __CORRELATION_TABLE,
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('dim_BTC_Price'[price]) ^ 2,
            __SelectedCurrency
        )
    )

VAR __SUM_Y2 =
    SUMX(
        __CORRELATION_TABLE,
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('fact_marketPrices'[price]) ^ 2,
            __SelectedCurrency
        )
    )

RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        __COUNT * __SUM_XY - __SUM_X * __SUM_Y * 1.,
        SQRT(
            (__COUNT * __SUM_X2 - __SUM_X ^ 2)
                * (__COUNT * __SUM_Y2 - __SUM_Y ^ 2)
        )
    )
```

It looks like it should work, but I'm getting the following error:
`"The True/False expression does not specify a column. Each True/False expressions used as a table filter expression must refer to exactly one column."` 
I actually cannot see any True/False expression in this formula.
Can you explain to me, what might be the cause of this error and how to fix it?

Or maybe there's a completely different, easier way to achieve the same result I want?